# SharePoint Performance Point Custom Filter Renderer Class Error

Tags: sharepoint, performancepoint

I have two servers (Server A and Server B) in one SharePoint 2010 farm.  I am getting following error on SharePoint Dashboard page while using the custom PPS filter webpart on Dashboard.

I have used Microsoft PerformancePoint Services SDK sample as base and created a custom Rendered class to define in FilterEditor Class as

```
filter.RendererClassName = typeof(CustomFilter).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

Critial Error:

> > 0x0500   PerformancePoint Service        PerformancePoint Services       4   Critical    An unexpected error occurred.  Error 20798.  Exception details: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: An unknown error has occurred. If the problem persists contact an administrator. There may be additional information in the server application event log.    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:... c9c0a044-c18d-4374-ad6f-e99d2a2959cd

Critial Error:

> > PerformancePoint Services        4   Critical    ...      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.IBIMonitoringServiceApplication.GetFilterDependencies(RepositoryLocation filterLocation)     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationProxy.<>c_*DisplayClassbb.b*_ba(IBIMonitoringServiceApplication channel)     at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(CodeBlock codeBlock)    c9c0a044-c18d-4374-ad6f-e99d2a2959cd

And finally:

> > PerformancePoint Services        ef8z    Critical    An exception occurred while rendering a Web control. The following diagnostic information might help to determine the cause of this problem:  Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BpmException: There was a problem preparing the WebPart for display.  PerformancePoint Services error code 20700.   c9c0a044-c18d-4374-ad6f-e99d2a2959cd

Please advice what I should do to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the web.config file, how did you specifiy the assembly for the renderer? It should be in this format: 
Namespace.Class name, DLL name, DLL version number, DLL culture, DLL public key token

And it should look something like the RendererClass in this example:

```
<CustomFCO type="Filter" subType="SampleFilter">
    <Resources FCOName="Custom Filter" FCODescription="This is my custom filter." />
    <RendererClass name="Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.ServerRendering.MultiSelectTreeViewControl, 
Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.ServerRendering, Version=14.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
    <EditorURI uri="/_layouts/SampleFilterEditor.aspx" />
</CustomFCO>
```

(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556434.aspx)